# Where is the phpMyAdmin of XAMPP mac version?

Tags: mac, xampp, phpmyadmin

I installed the XAMPP in my Mac, but I can not find

[image: snapshot]

[image: snapshot]

I can not find phpMyAdmin entrance, who can tell me where is it?

---

**EDIT-01**

I tried use the url: `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/`
but there is no path.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /phpMyAdmin/ was not found on this server.
```